# Upload video to facebook with php-sdk graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have seen an example in facebook documentation.

```
$post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?"
. "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc 
. "&". $access_token;
```

But i want to do this in facebook php-sdk.

```
$facebook->api('/me/videos/');
```

But it seems the video server is https://graph-video.facebook.com.
So how do i do this in graph api using php-sdk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

through graph its much more simple

To a group you can do this:

```
<?php
$app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
$app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
$my_url = "YOUR_POST_LOGIN_URL";
$video_title = "TITLE FOR THE VIDEO";
$video_desc = "DESCRIPTION FOR THE VIDEO";
$group_id = "YOUR_GROUP_ID";

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

echo '<html><body>';

if(empty($code)) {
   $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
     . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
     . "&scope=publish_stream";
    echo('<script>top.location.href="' . $dialog_url . '";</script>');
}

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
    . "&code=" . $code;
$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

$post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/" . $group_id . "/videos?"
    . "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc
    . "&". $access_token;

echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" '.$post_url.' "  
     method="POST">';
echo 'Please choose a file:';
echo '<input name="file" type="file">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" />';
echo '</form>';

echo '</body></html>';
?>
```

to a page you can do this

```
<?php
$app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
$app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
$my_url = "YOUR_POST_LOGIN_URL";
$video_title = "TITLE FOR THE VIDEO";
$video_desc = "DESCRIPTION FOR THE VIDEO";
$page_id = "YOUR_PAGE_ID"; // Set this to your APP_ID for Applications

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

echo '<html><body>';

if(empty($code)) {
  // Get permission from the user to publish to their page. 
  $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages";
  echo('<script>top.location.href="' . $dialog_url . '";</script>');
} else {

  // Get access token for the user, so we can GET /me/accounts
  $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
      . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
      . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
      . "&code=" . $code;
  $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

  $accounts_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?" . $access_token;
  $response = file_get_contents($accounts_url);

  // Parse the return value and get the array of accounts we have
  // access to. This is returned in the data[] array. 
  $resp_obj = json_decode($response,true);
  $accounts = $resp_obj['data'];

  // Find the access token for the page to which we want to post the video.
  foreach($accounts as $account) {
       if($account['id'] == $page_id) {
         $access_token = $account['access_token'];
         break;
       }
  }

  // Using the page access token from above, create the POST action
  // that our form will use to upload the video.
  $post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/" . $page_id . "/videos?"
      . "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc
      . "&access_token=". $access_token;

  // Create a simple form 
  echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" '.$post_url.' "  
       method="POST">';
  echo 'Please choose a file:';
  echo '<input name="file" type="file">';
  echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" />';
  echo '</form>';
}

echo '</body></html>';
?>
```

Comment: Using this coding, how can i get the response back from facebook?

Comment: after submit you will recieve the "VIDEO_ID" that will send to you an object with sucess or not, but it can take like 10min to upload depending on the size of the video

Comment: Thanks. It works. The video is displayed in facebook after few mins from upload. is it normal? Do you know how to tag friends from that video?

Comment: that i dont know cause i never did it, you need to search now, as possible mark your question as answered :)

Comment: @RicardoVieira can you write new php-sdk 4.0 tutorial for us ? i try upload some fb page video to my fb page upload. without download want this. this is possible ?

Comment: @RicardoVieira worked for me also even i got the video id and notification on my facebook page but video not showing in page news feed. what would be the problem ??