# Facebook Video Upload OAuthExecption 200 Error

Tags: php, facebook, file-upload, oauth

I have similar code to this (found at: [Upload video to facebook with php-sdk graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481148/upload-video-to-facebook-with-php-sdk-graph-api)) in an application I wrote, but yesterday I started receiving the OAuthException error. I looked for a simple video upload example to a Facebook page to test, and it returns the same 200 OAuthException.  I have tried modifying the permissions to include video_upload

Suggestions anyone?

I just checked and the example below comes from Facebook's page on how to upload videos.  It does not work.

`

```
$app_id             = "";// SET TO APP ID
$app_secret         = "";// SET TO APP SECRET
$my_url             = "";// SET TO URL
$video_title        = "TITLE FOR THE VIDEO";
$video_desc         = "DESCRIPTION FOR THE VIDEO";
$page_id            = " "; // Set this to your APP_ID for Applications
$code                   = $_REQUEST["code"];

echo '<html><body>';

if(empty($code)) {
    // Get permission from the user to publish to their page. 
    $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&scope=publish_stream,manage_pages";
    echo('<script>top.location.href="' . $dialog_url . '";</script>');
    } else {
// Get access token for the user, so we can GET /me/accounts
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
. "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
. "&code=" . $code;
$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

$accounts_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?" . $access_token;
$response = file_get_contents($accounts_url);

// Parse the return value and get the array of accounts we have
// access to. This is returned in the data[] array. 
$resp_obj = json_decode($response,true);
$accounts = $resp_obj['data'];

// Find the access token for the page to which we want to post the video.
foreach($accounts as $account) {
    if($account['id'] == $page_id) {
        $access_token = $account['access_token'];
        break;
    }
}

// Using the page access token from above, create the POST action
// that our form will use to upload the video.
$post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/" . $page_id . "/videos?"
. "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc
. "&access_token=". $access_token;

// Create a simple form 
echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" '.$post_url.' "  
   method="POST">';
echo 'Please choose a file:';
echo '<input name="file" type="file">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" />';
echo '</form>';
}
echo '</body></html>';
?>`
```

I keep receiving this error: 
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) App does not have permission to post to target",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}

Comment: Hi @MtRoxx. I am facing the same issue. Videos was uploading till the day before yesterday, but started throwing issue on yesterday. 
The message response is same as yours. I had lodged a bug regarding this on Facebook. So please report this to facebook. 

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/221714001339683?browse=external_tasks_search_results_528d96ad51c5d3a00812374

Comment: its strange i am also getting the same issue from yesterday and not able to upload my videos on fb pages, it give me below error { "error": { "message": "(#200) App does not have permission to post to target", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 200 }

Comment: Hi Ray and welcome to the club. Right now I'm double checking everything I know to make sure the settings are correct.  I'm using this to check permissions:  $permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
if( array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) ) {
    // Permission is granted!
    // Do the related task
    echo "I have permissions!<br>";
} else {
    // We don't have the permission
    // Alert the user or ask for the permission!
  echo "no permission <br >";
}

Comment: For the record I have other code that creates a FB object.  I will post a link to it tomorrow.

Comment: According to the permissions array, I have the correct permissions.  I am at a loss at what to do next.  Any ideas?  $permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($permissions);
 echo "</pre>";

Comment: Thank you @DeepakGangore I have reported the bug.

Comment: On iOS using Facebook SDK it happens the same. I have checked permissions and page access token. It works okey for images and texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to share good news. This bug has been solved now.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in Facebook's video upload code.  [Link to Face book Support Request](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/221714001339683?browse=external_tasks_search_results_528d96ad51c5d3a00812374)  Thank you [Deepak Gangore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2119861/deepakgangore) for your input and registering the bug with Facebook.

Comment: So I've learning a great deal about Facebook and their support requests.  After 10 days and a few comments, I went to log into Facebook and there was a survey they wanted me to take - I have never been asked for a survey before.  So I answered the questions and told them I was dissatisfied with their support.  The next day we had a thank you for your patience message.  The first message we received.

Comment: I am currently working on a way to upload videos to a YouTube channel and will link YouTube to a Facebook page.  Any other suggestions would be appreciated.