# How to post on Facebook Page using graph api

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are using Facebook graph api to share videos on facebook, when user share Facebook video on his wall at same time we are sharing same video on Facebook App page.

Following is the code we have used to share video on App page,

```
   NSDictionary *videoObject = @{
                                  @"title": self.videoDetails.videoTitle,
                                  @"contentType": @"video/quicktime",
                                  @"description": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",self.videoDetails.videoDescription,tag],
                                  [pathURL absoluteString]: videoData
                                  };
    FBRequest *uploadRequest = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/videos",kPage_ID]
                                                    parameters:videoObject
                                                    HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [uploadRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
```

So as we post video on user wall we use "me/videos" and if we want to post on page i am using "page_id/videos", and it was working fine but recently something has changed and now its not allowing to post on app page, giving error.

```
  error =         {
        code = 200;
        message = "(#200) App does not have permission to post to target";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
```

Is anyone faced same issue recently.

Comment: which permissions are you requesting, when opening FB Session?

Comment: using publish_stream,user_videos,read_stream, just found a bug report on facebook looks like many users on different platforms facing same issue https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/221714001339683?browse=external_tasks_search_results_528d96ad51c5d3a00812374]

Comment: It looks like it is the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110277/facebook-video-upload-oauthexecption-200-error

Comment: @curial yes its same, not sure when facebook will fix it.

Comment: this issue is fixed by facebook and now its working fine.