# Post video on Facebook Page

Tags: ios, facebook, video, sdk

I'm posting a video to a Facebook profile using the iOS SDK, and it works okey. But when I try to use the same code, and post the native video to a Facebook Page, it fails with the following error:

**(#200) App does not have permission to post to target**

I'm using the right URL (https://graph-video.facebook.com/pageID/videos) and also I have replaced the user session token, with the Page token.

In fact, posting a photo works okey. But not a video.

What does it mean that "the app does not have permission to post to target"? Should I use a special permission in order to post a video on a page?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this can help..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110277/facebook-video-upload-oauthexecption-200-error

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the Facebook's video upload code, which hasn't been fixed yet. You can track the updates on this bug using [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/221714001339683).